# How to post data to sanity cms

Tags: javascript, react-native, sanity

Hi I want to POST more data on my sanity project database. To add data to the server like we do in the sanity studio

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add to / edit your data using the [Mutation API](https://www.sanity.io/docs/http-mutations) or the `patch` method on the [client](https://www.sanity.io/docs/js-client#patch-update-a-document). The [other clients](https://www.sanity.io/docs/client-libraries) (.NET, PHP, etc.) have equivalent methods.